# The argument "name" is required, but no definition was found

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

I am using the following configuration to create EKS CLUSTER with terraform module EKS and then get cluster object information in data by getting cluster object by passing cluster_id, but it is not getting cluster information. Instead, it gives the following error that it could find no name but I am providing reference to EKS cluster to get name from.

```
            provider "kubernetes" {
            #load_config_file = "false"
            host = data.aws_eks_cluster.myapp-cluster.endpoint
            token = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.myapp-cluster.token
            cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.myapp-cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
        }

        data "aws_eks_cluster" "myapp-cluster"{
            name = module.eks.cluster_id
        }

        data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "myapp-cluster" {
            name = module.eks.cluster_id
        }   

        output "cc-name" {
            value = module.eks.cluster_id
        }

        module "eks" {
        source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
        version = "19.16.0"

        cluster_name = "myapp-eks-cluster"
        cluster_version = "1.27"
        
        subnet_ids = module.myapp-vpc.private_subnets
        vpc_id = module.myapp-vpc.vpc_id

        tags = {
            environment = "development"
            application = "myapp"
        }

        eks_managed_node_groups = [
            {
                instance_type = "t2.small"
                name = "worker-group-1"
                asg_desired_capacity = 2
            },
            {
                instance_type = "t2.medium"
                name = "worker-group-2"
                asg_desired_capacity = 1
            },
        ]
        }
```

#### Error

```
Error: Missing required argument

with data.aws_eks_cluster.myapp-cluster,
on eks-cluster.tf line 9, in data “aws_eks_cluster” “myapp-cluster”:
9: name = module.eks.cluster_id

The argument “name” is required, but no definition was found.

Error: Missing required argument

with data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.myapp-cluster,
on eks-cluster.tf line 13, in data “aws_eks_cluster_auth” “myapp-cluster”:
13: name = module.eks.cluster_id

The argument “name” is required, but no definition was found.
```

Comment: `module.eks.cluster_id` is probably `null`.

Answer (score 4):

From checking the docs of the `cluster_id` output of the `terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws` module you are using here

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest?tab=outputs:

cluster_id
Description: The ID of the EKS cluster. Note: currently a value is returned only for local EKS clusters created on Outposts

Which means @marcin is correct, the value is null - (When the inputted value is null its considered as if no definition was provided).

Instead, try using the `cluster_name` output
`cluster_name` Description: The name of the EKS cluster

In any case, from checking the documentation of the needed input here:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/eks_cluster#name

`name` - (Required) Name of the cluster. Must be between 1-100 characters in length. Must begin with an alphanumeric character, and must only contain alphanumeric characters, dashes and underscores (^[0-9A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-_]+$).

What you need is the name, not the id anyway.

Therefore, I suggest you try using `module.eks.cluster_name`.

Good luck!